# React with MUI's useStyles() giving me a hooks rules violation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm getting the dreaded React "Invalid Hook Call" error and I'm not running any hooks.

1. Installed React using CRA
2. Installed MUI
3. Built simple styles page:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  layout: {
    minHeight: '230px',
  },
}));

export default useStyles;
```

4. Added styles to component:

```
import React from 'react';
import useStyles from './styles';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';

const SimpleComponent = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Container className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <div>Page Content</div>;
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default SimpleComponent;
```

The app returns no errors on `npm start`, but the page itself gives me the invalid hook call pointing to the line `const classes = useStyles();`.  That's not a hook.

I've tried re `npm install`ing the app, I've tried moving the call all around, no matter what I do I get that same page.  Looks like a lot of people have had similar problems with this configuration but no other solutions have addressed my problem.

Hooks Error Page:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See[https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html][1] for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

SimpleComponent
src/Components/PaymentHistory/PaymentHistory.js:7
   4 | import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
   5 | 
   6 | const SimpleComponent = (props) => {
>  7 |   const classes = useStyles();
   8 |   return (
   9 |     <React.Fragment>
  10 |       <Container className={classes.root}>
View compiled
```

Comment: Are you sure the file styles.js has the useStyles ?  I checked your code , and works perfectly fine.

Comment: Could you re-create the problem with this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-https-3u9cm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)? Your code works fine just like @CevaComic mentions when I test it.

Comment: `useStyles` **is** a custom hook. Please show how you use `SimpleComponent`.

Comment: @Hangindev I reconstructed the file in the code sandbox and it works fine.  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-with-muis-usestyles-giving-me-a-hooks-rules-violation-4bfx9?file=/src/Components/SimpleComponent/styles.js

Comment: Some of the things that are listed in package.json are different though....

Comment: @Hangindev I installed material-ui without creating the dependency in package.json, so the component couldn't find the MUI library. Adding that in manually and re-installing the build solved the problem.  Since your comment helped me figure that out if you want to turn it into an answer I'd be glad to give you the points.

Comment: Glad you figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure all the dependencies(including @material-ui/core) are correctly installed.

Here is a working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-https-3u9cm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks!